# How to use internet through VPN in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have DSL connection. I need to know how to setup and use openVPN.

Comment: What did you try? What were the problems?

Comment: @guntbert I was looking for it but there are tutorials for outdated versions of Ubuntu with different networking menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to install the openvpn and openvpn network manager plugin packages:

`sudo apt-get install openvpn`
`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`

2. Setup your openvpn session:

   2.1 - In your network connections go to VPN - set up VPN, then choose add connection type VPN - OpenVPN, click on Create or import a saved ovpn configuration.
   [image]
   [image]
   2.2 - In the editing of your VPN connection window you configure in **general** IP address or host name of your VPN provider
   [image]

   2.3 - choose the required certificates and keys / user name and password.

   2.4 - In the **special** you set up VPN connection details such as port, LZO compression, TCP, UDP, TAP device - these are settings from your VPN provider.

   2.5 - Set up the security tab according to your VPN provider. Finally click on save to save the new VPN settings.
3. To try the new VPN go again to your network connections - VPN and click on the newly created VPN.

   [image]
   [image]

Please note that even if you get a successful connection message and do not get any traffic through, then your settings are incorrect.

Good guide is on [this](http://www.frogiswrong.com/blog/articles/8/openvpn-on-openwrt-a-little-more-detail) site. Please note that there is also server and client setup as well. As a server you might want to run a device which runs 24/7, such as router or nas.

You can see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56O2WeMZAr0) video how to setup in Ubuntu 14.04 in unity desktop.

The screenshoots have been taken from [this site](http://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=53).

For ovpn configuration you may use the public VPN service [here](http://www.vpngate.net)

Comment: I can't do what you talking about, are you sure that you talking about 14.04 ? About the guide - harder way is not the best.

Comment: The guide is for Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity desktop. With Xfce or KDE you have to look in appropriate place. The network manager is in the same place as your DSL connection. If you have unity, click on the DSL icon in the top bar and expand the menu, then you can go to the VPN....

Comment: right, you'd better use screenshots

Comment: Please check the video, that shows it better than screenshoots. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56O2WeMZAr0